# Android app facebook integration failure

Tags: android, facebook, posting

I have a problem with my app and I don't know if the problem is obvious.
I have managed to post things to my facebook wall using the app I have created for Android.
But when I distribute this app to my testers, they don't get to the login window. The app is terminated before the screen appears.

I have used the tutorial:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Can somebody help me. Are some things I can check or is there a more thorough explanation available on the internet?

Comment: Can you show some code or at least logs?

Comment: is this app is working on your emulator or not?

Comment: I will post mye code here when I get home from work, plus additional info.

Comment: Ok.Take look at this file: http://tylldalen.no-vgs.org/DogFace.java

Comment: What happens for my users is that they don`t get to the FB login window before the app crashes and now I can`t login as I have been able to before. A bit strange and unstable. But the code might tell you someting that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow following steps,

1.) go to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples

2.) download the example named **Hackbook**.
    and execute it , this is working example of facebook integration with android

Here condition is that you must have **App ID** and **App secret**.
   if is there any problem let me know.

Comment: Take a look at my comments above.